# Trouble with isolating a particular address in a for loop

Tags: java, loops

First off, I am trying to write a program that allows 10 seats on an airplane(Ten seats are already allocated in the seatArray[]). When a user inputs what type of seat they want (First Class or Coach Class) this method I am trying to create must take the first seat in that section and mark it as reserved(previously defined method). I have the method in this shape at the moment with a while loop and a for loop. Here's a section of the method:

```
`boolean flag = true;
    if (spec.equals("First Class"))
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
        {
            while(flag)
            {
                seatArray[i] = new Seat(i, spec);
                if(seatArray[i].checkSeatAvailability() == true)
                {
                    seatArray[i].reserveSeat();
                    flag = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }`
```

any suggestions as to how I would go about  assign it, if not, then go to the next seat?

Comment: I notice that `flag` will never be set back to `true` after one successful run through the loop.

Comment: you should first clearly specify what the problem is??

Comment: There are many simpler ways to do this. Is this an assignment where you should be using one particular programming idiom, or are you just looking for the cleanest/most efficient solution?

Comment: @Charles I could use more than one, but this is what I'm working with right now

Comment: I think your main problem is that you really should get a better order for your flow control.

I.e. my check order would basically be more like this:
for seats -> if type matches -> if is open -> reserve and return

Comment: @Charles im not completely sure I understand what you're saying. The method's return type is void. What do you mean by return?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the while(flag) and change the code as follows:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 4 && flag ; i++)
    {
            seatArray[i] = new Seat(i, spec);
            if(seatArray[i].checkSeatAvailability() == true)
            {
                seatArray[i].reserveSeat();
                flag = false;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: this seems only assigns the first seat. It does assign the next seat

Comment: His spec indicates that the seats are already initialized. I'm assuming he has some sort of state variable that he'll need to toggle over to 'taken', rather than wiping out the already existing Seat object in the array.

Comment: mine was a free interpretation to digital cubism

Answer (score 0):

I would define my `Seat` class like so:

```
public class Seat {
    private static final String ECONOMY = "Economy";
    private static final String FIRST_CLASS = "First Class";
    private String seatingClass = ECONOMY;
    private boolean reserved = false;

    // Default, economy and not reserved. 
    public Seat() {
    }

    public Seat( String seatingClass, boolean reserved ) {
        this.seatingClass = seatingClass;
        this.reserved = reserved;
    }

    public void setIsReserved( boolean reserved ) {
        this.reserved = reserved;
    }

    public boolean isReserved() {
        return reserved;
    }
    // more getters/setters...
}
```

Later on you can populate the seats array with un reserved seats, and you can go through and reserve them if they arent reserved using `isReserved()` and `setIsReserved(..)`.